# Extending SecurityExpressionRoot for Access in @Query

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa

My rest API is secured with OAuth2 and I want to be able to write @Queries so that only entities owned by the user are displayed. Actually, the use is part of a tenant and the entities are owned by the tenant rather than the user. The tenant identifier can be derived from the scopes in the JWT token.

My thinking was, I should be able to provide a custom SecurityExpressionRoot that takes care of deriving that tenant from the scopes and providing the value for use in the @Query annotation. This is the EvaluationContextExtension and SecurityExpressionRoot I made for this:

```
@Component
public class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension implements EvaluationContextExtension {

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
    }
    
    
    public static class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot {
        public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
            super(authentication);  
        }
        
        public String getTenant() {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

}
```

In the Repository, I want to be able to access the tenant property and construct the query with it:

```
public interface SubscriptionRepo extends CrudRepository<Subscription, Long> {
    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
    @Query("SELECT a FROM Subscription a WHERE a.owner = HOW_TO_ACCESS_THE_TENANT?")
    @Override
    Iterable<Subscription> findAll();
}
```

I put "HOW_TO_ACCESS_THE_TENANT?" because that's where I currently struggle. I have tried many things I found on the internet like ?#{#security.tenant}, ?#{tenant}, ?#{getTenant()}, ?#{#security.getTenant()} but nothing seems to work.

`?#{#security.tenant}` => `SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'tenant' cannot be found on null`

`?#{#security.getTenant()}` => `SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getTenant() on null context object`

`?#{tenant}` => `SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'tenant' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?`

I am not sure if I did something wrong implementing that custom security root, or my query is wrong or maybe it just doesn't work at all that way. Can someone provide direction?

Answer (score 1):

Found out properties need to be explicitly listed in a Map exposed via `EvaluationContextExtension#getProperties`. I have never seen this in any documentation but came across it reading one of the error messages. So the working implementation of `EvaluationContextExtension` with a custom `SecurityExpressionRoot` looks like this:

```
@Component
public class EditTenantEvaluationContextExtension implements EvaluationContextExtension {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(EvaluationContextExtension.super.getProperties());
        properties.put("tenants", getRootObject().getTenants());
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
    }
    
    
    public static class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot {
        public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
            super(authentication);
        }

        public Set<String> getTenants() {
            return SecurityUtils.getTenants();
        }
    }

}
```

The query needs to look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Subscription a WHERE a.owner = ?#{security.tenants}")
```